# ¿ UINavigationController como ir a una vista anterior por código?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Tengo en el storyboard una vista inicial creada con su navigationController mediante "Embed in". Desde esta vista inicial tengo otras vistas que están enlazadas mediante "segues". Estas vistas enlazadas heredan también la barra de navegación creada al principio. Para ir de la vista inicial a las otras vistas uso "performSegue con su identificador".¿  Como puedo por código ir a la vista anterior sin usar segues, ni unwind ?

He probado borrando el contenido childviewControllers ( Solo me sale el primero)  que hay en el NavigationController instanciado y sustituyendo por alguna otra vista que hay enlazado con los segues. Al hacer esto me aparece la vista pero sin el navegador y mi deseo es que aparezca con el navegador que heredaba...

```
// screenStart es un NavigationController.
// Borro el viewController dentro del Navigation Controller para cambiarlo por otro y así dar un salto a otra vista.

if self.screenStart.childViewControllers.count > 0 {
        var viewControllers:[UIViewController] = self.screenStart.childViewControllers
        viewControllers.removeAll() }

if self.screenStart.view.subviews.count > 0 {            
    var viewns:[UIView] = self.screenStart.view.subviews
    viewns.removeAll()
}

// Voy a otra vista
var otherScreen = UIViewController()
    otherScreen =  (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OneViewController"))! as! OneViewController

   self.screenStart.addChildViewController(otherScreen)
   self.screenStart.view.addSubview((otherScreen.view))
```

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer lo que quieres deberías usar alguno de estos métodos de `UINavigationController` (según lo que necesites):

> `func popViewController(animated: Bool)`: Saca el último *view controller* volviendo al inmediatamente anterior.
>
> `func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)`: Saca todos los *view controllers* hasta la raíz del *navigation controller*.
>
> `func popToViewController(UIViewController, animated: Bool)`: Saca todos los *view controllers* hasta llegar al especificado en el parámetro.

Fuente: [UINavigationController reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) (en inglés).

Por ejemplo, con este código

```
if self.screenStart.childViewControllers.count > 0 {
    var viewControllers:[UIViewController] = self.screenStart.childViewControllers
    viewControllers.removeAll()
}
```

entiendo que quieres volver al inicio de la navegación. Eso lo lograrías con

```
self.screenStart.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: El problema es que no puedo ir a una vista anterior con pop ya que pop me borraría la vista del stack y no quiero que la borre ( quiero que conserve los datos ).

Comment: Es decir imaginando que tengo 5 vistas, he ido avanzando de la primera vista a la quinta por medio de segues y rellenando unos datos en cada vista. En un momento dado quiero ir a la vista de la posición 3 pero si lo hago con pop retrocediendo 2 veces de la 5 a la 3 entonces me borra la vista 4 y 5 con los datos que contenían. Usando unwind desde la vista 5 puedo ir a la 3 sin que me borre los datos de las otras vistas. Pero ahora de la vista 3 donde estoy quiero ir a la 5 sin usar segue que me haga pasar por la vista 4 y sin crear otro segue desde la vista 3 a la 5.

Comment: Es decir deseo un comportamiento parecido a tabBar pero que contenga cada vista su barra superios del navigationController.